# How to use PHP to rotate PNG images

Tags: php, image, rotation

So right now I am using PHP to add rotate functionality to images. Currently right now it is set up to only work for JPEGs, but I need to allow it to work with the image file types PNG and GIF. PNG is more the more important of the two. So currently my code is:

```
<?php

include_once('../classes/sitewide-functions.php');

$server_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$auction = $_GET['auction'];
$item = $_GET['item'];
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$img = urldecode($_GET['img']);

$image = explode('/',$img);
//parse out the file name
$folder = '/'.$image[3].'/';

$file = $image[4];
$image = $folder.$file;
$imagePath = $server_root.$image;

//set the correct direction
if ($dir == 'ccw') {
    $degrees = 90;
} else {
    $degrees = '270';
}
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);

$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);



//delete the old file
unlink($imagePath);
$newFile = 'img_'.$item.'_'.time().'.jpg';


$imageStatus = imagejpeg($rotate, $imagePath);


$typeString = null;
$typeInt = exif_imagetype($imagePath);
switch($typeInt) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
$typeString = 'image/gif';
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
$typeString = 'image/jpeg';
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    $typeString = 'image/png';
    break;
  default:
    $typeString = 'unknown';
}


$imageSize = getimagesize($imagePath);

$imageFileSize = filesize($imagePath);

imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);

$newImage = array(
    "name" => array(
    0 => $file,
    ),
    "type" => array(
        0 => $typeString,
    ),
    "tmp_name" => array(
        0 => $imagePath,
    ),
    "error" => array(
        0 => $imageStatus,
    ),
    "size" => array(
        0 => $imageFileSize,
    )
);

processImageSizes($imagePath); ?>
```

So that is was I have right now and it is working for JPEG images. I tried adding a switch case for the PHP functions imagecreatefromjpeg and imagejpeg, but when I added those it made the page go dead. So wasn't sure the next step to take to make this code snippet work for pngs and gifs.

EDIT: The error I am receiving on the dead page is: HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: `imagecreatefromjpeg()` ... well, there are also functions `imagecreatefrompng()` and `imagecreatefromgif()` - just detect the MIME type and use the relevant function.

Comment: @CD001 Not too familiar with MIME type. I did try adding a switch case for those php functions where I used: $typeInt = exif_imagetype($imagePath); to try and figure out file type

Comment: are you sure you dont want to use CSS for this?

Comment: File type, [MIME Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) ... tom-a-toes, tom-ah-toes ;)

Comment: @Universus I don't want to use CSS because the image that is rotated will then be saved with that rotation on the server. So it's not just a styles thing